# RDL report format time to hh:mm:ss tt format for is-IS culture

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, culture, rdl, time-format

I am working with SSRS and developing one report, in that I want to format time in to **hh:mm:ss tt** format. 
My expression in report is like:

```
Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss tt")
```

For **en-US** culture it is giving proper result as 04:05:56 PM but when I set report language as **is-IS** it is formatting time in to 12 hour format but without **AM/PM**.

I also tried setting time format with AM/PM in text box properties but same result I am getting like above.